# WCF Data Services returning a complex type is not in ATOM format

Tags: entity-framework, windows-phone-7, wcf-data-services

I've been struggling with this one for days and think I've got the problem isolated down to a serialization issue.

I've got a WCF Data Service and I'm calling a stored procedure that pulls in a datasets (n number of rows).  The data service is using the Function Import and it returns a Complex Type.  The service works fine it returns the following in the browser:

<GetChanges xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices" >
<element xmlns:p2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" p2:type="tasksModel.fxGetChangeList_Result">

<CHANGE>DELETE</CHANGE>

<ID p2:type="Edm.Int32">116</ID>

<UpdateVersion p2:type="Edm.Int64">703</UpdateVersion>

</element>

</GetChanges>

But when i call this data from the client (a windows phone app) no results are returned.  I've confirmed that the url directly is pulling down the data above.

Here is the client's call...

```
_changes.LoadCompleted += new EventHandler<System.Data.Services.Client.LoadCompletedEventArgs>(Items_LoadCompleted);

_changes.LoadAsync(new Uri(theUrl, UriKind.Absolute));
```

And here is the callback

```
void Items_LoadCompleted(object sender, System.Data.Services.Client.LoadCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        int count = _changes.Count;
        _changes.ToList().ForEach( x=>{
        ....
   });
```

No errors are thrown simply no results are returned.

What I've realized is the xml above from the Data Service is NOT in atom format.  The only thing I can think of is that the client can't serialize the data in the complex type because its not in Atom format.

So I have 3 questions:
1. Has anyone else encountered this?
2. Is there a client workaround to serialize the complex type?
3. Is there a server-side work around to serialize the complex into Atom?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) This is a known limitation of the client library.

2) Currently not supported by the client library. The usual workaround is to either return an entity type from the server, or parse the response yourself (typically using XLinq)

3) There's no ATOM format for complex types. To get ATOM the server would need to return an entity type.

Comment: Many thanks. I would have spent many more hours trying to debug.  In general, I'm finding that having to learn the client behaviors and conform to much of the protocol is more effort than its worth.  I'm substituting hours writing code for hours debugging.

I think for most of my use cases I'm better off simply exposing a non-Data Service WCF Service with webHttpBindings and exposing my objects that way. I get more control of the payload size and more control of the actual objects sent.

My primary uses case is exposing SQL Azure data to web and mobile clients.  Am I overlooking something?

Comment: It heavily depends on your requirements. OData (WCF DS) is great if you need the ability for the clients to ask questions which you don't know upfront. If you know the questions clients will ask you can do that in non-OData WCF service. On the other hand, in OData it's harder to implement some specific bussiness logic in some cases, for which WCF is usually easier. So if you only want to tie your service to your client and you control both and you can hardcode queries on the server, then plain WCF services will work. If you need some freedom on the client, you migth want OData.